# Rename/Backup old directory in python

Tags: python, directory, rename

I have a script that creates a new directory regularly. I would like to check if it already exists and if so move the existing folder to a backup. My first iteration was

```
if os.path.isdir(destination_path):
   os.rename(destination_path,destination_path + '_old')
```

However, if there already one being backed up it will obviously crash. What I would like to do is find the number of directories that match the destination_path and append that number like a version number.

```
if os.path.isdir(destination_path):
   n = get_num_folders_like(destination_path)
   os.rename(destination_path,destination_path + str(n))
```

I am just not sure how to make such a hypothetical function. I think fnmatch might work but I can't get the syntax right.

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of backup directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to move the old directory aside, renumbering can easily be done by listing all directories by the same name, then picking last one by extracting the numeric maximum from the matching names.

Listing the directories can be done by using the [`glob` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob); it combines listing files with the `fnmatch` module to filter:

```
 import glob

if os.path.isdir(destination_path):
     # match all paths starting with the destination name, plus at least
     # an underscore and one digit.
     backups = glob.glob(destination_path + '_[0_9]*')
     def extract_number(path):
         try:
             # assume everything after `_` is a number
             return int(path.rpartition('_')[-1])
         except ValueError:
             # not everything was a number, skip this directory
             return None

     backup_numbers = (extract__number(b) for b in backups)
     try:
         next_backup = max(filter(None, backup_numbers)) + 1
     except ValueError:
         # no backup directories
         next_backup = 1

os.rename(destination_path,destination_path + '_{:d}'.format(next_backup))
```

I'm assuming you are not worried about race conditions here.

Comment: Why do you think it would fail with this method? Are you concerned about race conditions? Each time it would run it would check for similar files and move the one which is currently destination_path. This process is triggered manually so a race condition would not be an issue. I do not understand your example. Creating a unique and interpretable 'file_name' is the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: @Keith: right, I misunderstood you then; you said that *if there already one being backed up it will obviously crash*. I interpreted that as *if one is **being backed up at the same time***, because in that case your code will indeed raise an exception as the target directory already exists.

Comment: @Keith: answered the 'renumbering based on existing dirs' question now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the more general answer given I ended up using something more streamlined for my specific case

```
if os.path.isdir(destination_path):
    n = len(glob.glob(destination_path + '*'))
    os.rename(destination_path, destination_path + '_' + str(n))
```